# Simple PHP function for echoing the results of an array, not showing all rows

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an issue with the code below. It will show only one row of 13 in the table. What am I doing wrong? I want it to show all the rows.

```
$query = 'SELECT xyz FROM mytable';

foreach ($query as $row) {
    $row->column1;
}

$result = $row->column1;
echo $result."<br>\n";
```

Comment: hi, perhaps move the `echo` to within the loop.

Comment: Ah duh. That would do it. Must not have been completing the loop? If you want to make that the answer I will accept. Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually doing anything with the loop.

Putting the echo in the loop will solve this.

```
$query = 'SELECT xyz FROM mytable';

foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo $row->column1."<br>\n";
}
```